# Why does this merge sort produce an index out of bounds exception when sorting a second array at the same time?

Tags: java

I've been working on a merge sort algorithm, which I want to use to sort a string array eventually.

The theory is that I sort an array containing the IDs that I want to sort in the same order as the main array which is a string, then sort the ID array and perform the same actions on the string array, theoretically sorting them both the same way.

For example, the array of ID values could be [1,2,3,4,5], and the main array would look something like ["Name, 1","Name, 2"]...

When I run the algorithm without including any of the second array parts it works correctly and this is the output:

`[0, 1, 1, 10, 12, 16, 18, 24, 26, 53, 53, 53, 100]`

But as soon as I try to add the second array operations, I get an exception saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at s4001175.ct5057.flight.Booker.merge(Booker.java:250)
    at s4001175.ct5057.flight.Booker.mergeSort(Booker.java:236)
    at s4001175.ct5057.flight.Booker.mergeSort(Booker.java:232)
    at s4001175.ct5057.flight.Booker.mergeSort(Booker.java:232)
    at s4001175.ct5057.flight.FlightManagement.passengerStatus(FlightManagement.java:92)
    at s4001175.ct5057.flight.FlightManagement.mainMenu(FlightManagement.java:53)
    at s4001175.ct5057.flight.FlightManagement.main(FlightManagement.java:27)
```

Code:

```
   public void mergeSort(int[] flightIDArr, int arrLength, String[] actualArr) {

//        Flattened array of bookings to 1d array
         String[] flatArray = flattenArray(readBookings());


//         If array does not need to be split as length is already 1
        if (arrLength < 2) {
            return;
        }

        // Middle of the array
        int mid = arrLength / 2;
        //Left array of length of half of the array
        int[] left = new int[mid];
        // Other half of split array, with arrLength-mid size to ensure that it works even if the array is an odd length
        int[] right = new int[arrLength - mid];

        //Mirrored version of previous lines but for string array of what we actually want to sort (booking info)
        String[] actualLeft = new String[mid];
        // Same as above but right side
        String[] actualRight = new String[arrLength - mid];

        // for the elements in left array
        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            // filling the left arrays with the info from the full array
            left[i] = flightIDArr[i];
            actualLeft[i] = flatArray[i];

        }
        // for elements in right array
        for (int i = mid; i < arrLength; i++) {
            // filling the right arrays with the info from the full array
            right[i - mid] = flightIDArr[i];
            actualRight[i - mid] = flatArray[i];
        }

        //recursively calls the mergesort algorithm to split the arrays as small as possible
        mergeSort(left, mid, actualLeft);
        mergeSort(right, arrLength - mid, actualRight);

        //re merges the split arrays
        merge(flightIDArr,actualArr, left, right, mid, arrLength - mid, actualLeft,actualRight);
    }

    //Method to merge all the split arrays
    public void merge(
            int[] flightIDArr, String[] actualArr, int[] leftArr, int[] rightArr, int left, int right, String[] actualLeft, String[] actualRight) {

        //setting up variables for looping
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        //
        while (i < left && j < right) {
            if (leftArr[i] <= rightArr[j]) {
                flightIDArr[k++] = leftArr[i++];
                actualArr[k++] = actualLeft[i++];
            }
            else {
                flightIDArr[k++] = rightArr[j++];
                actualArr[k++] = actualRight[j++];
            }
        }
        while (i < left) {
            flightIDArr[k++] = leftArr[i++];
            actualArr[k++] = actualLeft[i++];

        }
        while (j < right) {
            flightIDArr[k++] = rightArr[j++];
            actualArr[k++] = actualRight[j++];

        }
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(actualArr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flightIDArr));
    }
```

I've tried running through the program using the debugger in IntelliJ, and when the exception is produced to begin with at line 250, these are the values of the variables involved:

```
 leftArr: 0:0

actualLeft:

     0:
    "Booking Number: 1 
    Flight Number: 000 
    Passenger Name: Test Name 
    Seat Number: 1 
    Seat Class: First"
```

So it looks like when this stage in the code is reached it is trying to set values in these arrays outside of their range, and yet this does not occur when running the algorithm without the second array involved, despite seemingly the same situation occurring on line 249, where

```
  flightIDArr[k++] = leftArr[i++];
```

is called

Edit for new code:

Using the proposed answer I have changed my code, which seems to remove the error however the sorting no longer works correctly, and some numbers are noteven included:

The correct output:

```
 [0, 1, 1, 10, 12, 16, 18, 24, 26, 53, 53, 53, 100]
```

Vs the current output with the new code:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 12, 16, 18, 18, 24, 53, 53, 53, 100]
```

As you can see there are now duplicate and missing values from the original dataset.

Code:

```
   public void mergeSort(int[] flightIDArr, int arrLength, String[] actualArr) {

//        Flattened array of bookings to 1d array
         String[] flatArray = flattenArray(readBookings());


//         If array does not need to be split as length is already 1
        if (arrLength < 2) {
            return;
        }

        // Middle of the array
        int mid = arrLength / 2;
        //Left array of length of half of the array
        int[] left = new int[mid];
        // Other half of split array, with arrLength-mid size to ensure that it works even if the array is an odd length
        int[] right = new int[arrLength - mid];

        //Mirrored version of previous lines but for string array of what we actually want to sort (booking info)
        String[] actualLeft = new String[mid];
        // Same as above but right side
        String[] actualRight = new String[arrLength - mid];

        // for the elements in left array
        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            // filling the left arrays with the info from the full array
            left[i] = flightIDArr[i];
            actualLeft[i] = flatArray[i];

        }
        // for elements in right array
        for (int i = mid; i < arrLength; i++) {
            // filling the right arrays with the info from the full array
            right[i - mid] = flightIDArr[i];
            actualRight[i - mid] = flatArray[i];
        }

        //recursively calls the mergesort algorithm to split the arrays as small as possible
        mergeSort(left, mid, actualLeft);
        mergeSort(right, arrLength - mid, actualRight);

        //re merges the split arrays
        merge(flightIDArr,actualArr, left, right, mid, arrLength - mid, actualLeft,actualRight);
    }

    //Method to merge all the split arrays
    public void merge(
            int[] flightIDArr, String[] actualArr, int[] leftArr, int[] rightArr, int left, int right, String[] actualLeft, String[] actualRight) {

        //setting up variables for looping
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        //
        while (i < left && j < right) {
            if (leftArr[i] <= rightArr[j]) {
                flightIDArr[k] = leftArr[i];
                actualArr[k++] = actualLeft[i++];
            }
            else {
                flightIDArr[k] = rightArr[j];
                actualArr[k++] = actualRight[i++];
            }
        }
        while (i < left) {
            flightIDArr[k] = leftArr[i];
            actualArr[k++] = actualLeft[i++];

        }
        while (j < right) {
            flightIDArr[k] = rightArr[j];
            actualArr[k++] = actualRight[j++];

        }
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ActualArr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flightIDArr));
//        System.out.println(" Actual Array: \n \n  " +(Arrays.toString (actualArr)));
    }
```

Comment: there is one element in the array, and you are trying to access the second. that is bound to give problems

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that it works fine for the ID array which also only has 1 element at the time, so I'm confused by it

Comment: and who says that isn't the problem mentioned?

Comment: if the length is 2, then mid is 0 and `arrLength - mid` is again 2. basically the left array is length 0 and the right array is length 2 again. You do want to split it in 1 and 1 though, I assume, so what happens when mid would round up instead of down?

Comment: @Stultuske thank you for the suggestion, I see what you mean now thanks to the other proposed answer, where the value of the loop variables was increasing before it needed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `k++` `j++` etc. you increase the variable. You do this for both the left and the right array. But you probably only want to do it once, not twice.

You want to replace code like this:

```
if (leftArr[i] <= rightArr[j]) {
    flightIDArr[k++] = leftArr[i++];
    actualArr[k++] = actualLeft[i++];
}
```

With this:

```
if (leftArr[i] <= rightArr[j]) {
    flightIDArr[k] = leftArr[i];
    actualArr[k++] = actualLeft[i++];
}
```

Or this:

```
if (leftArr[i] <= rightArr[j]) {
    flightIDArr[k] = leftArr[i];
    actualArr[k] = actualLeft[i];
    k++; i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have also tested it by only doing the ++ for the first line when setting the value for the ID array and the exact same problem occurs.

Comment: No you want it on the last of the two lines. Otherwise the value has already increased for the second line.

Comment: Oh right, I see what you mean, I'll give it a try now, thanks

Comment: This seems to remove the error but causes me some more problems as it somehow messes up the sorting order, I'm gonna edit the post with the current code and output now

Comment: Sorting order was actually fine, I had accidentally written in a i instead of a j somewhere